# Is it possible to hide email account details while authenticating using MailKit?

Tags: vb.net, imap, mailkit

While authenticating our email account using MailKit (VB.net), as below code

```
clientIMAP.Authenticate("email@address.com", "myPassword")
```

Is it possible to "hide" my email address and password? This is because I am not the only who who will access the source code,, and I don't really wanna show my account details to the others.

Was thinking on creating an email account just for this project purpose, but still wants to know if there is any other way.

Comment: Not possible, I'm afraid. But you could make it read the password from a configuration file, and not grant others access to read that file.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for answering and your suggestion.